# Icons on workflow toolbox are blurred

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm re-hosting the designer in my own application. But I surprisingly found the icons in the toolbox are blurred. Screenshot is upload [here](http://img2.tu22.cn/28523.png).

It seems the toolbox is stretched, but the text is displayed correctly, only the icons are blurred. The screenshot was taken from one WF sample (WF_WCF_Samples\WF\Basic\DesignerRehosting\Basic\cs). The only change I made was making the toolbox list long enough, and assigning the same icon (16x16) to all the tools. You can find the sample codes [here](http://fs09n3.sendspace.com/dl/34c3a3a4c1e62d88df242752c94ad655/4db69e5c472f12ca/g911dn/IconsBlurred.zip).

Any idea what's going wrong? Is there any workaround available?

Thanks so much!
Donald

Comment: Just an idea... did you try to put SnapsToDevicePixels to true ?

Comment: Yes I did, but neither "true" nor "false" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Set UseLayoutRounding="True" on the Main Window. That fixes it.